# error An unexpected error occurred: "Command \"e2e\" not found."

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, jhipster, yarnpkg

i'm trying to run protractor tests with "yarn e2e" on a jhipster generated app.
As soon as i execute the command, i get the following error:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "Command \"e2e\" not found.".

Any idea on what can it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `package.json` for the `e2e` script.  If it isn't there, you didn't choose to add the Protracter test option when generating your project.  Note that your project needs to have a frontend for the Protracter test option to appear in the prompts.

Comment: Again, thanks! It was related to the previous question